# Asterisk audio capture on another machine on same LAN

Tags: asterisk, agi

Using Asterisk 13.12.1, which working fine. Also setup an AGI (AsterNet) on remote windows 10 machine which working fine too. Able to route calls to AGI on remote windows 10 machine fine, using like - exten => 1001,1,agi(agi://192.168.43.191/customivr)

Problem - I need to capture audio too on remote machine. There are different ways like EAGI, JACK_HOOK etc. But not able to find an starting point to use those.

1 JACK_HOOK - configured jack hook like -
exten => 1003,1,Set(JACK_HOOK(manipulate,s(default),i(system:playback_1))=on)
which seems configured correctly. But issue is how can I now get audio on remote windows 10 machine where AGI (AsterNet) configured already.

2 EAGI - Not found any sample to implement this on remote machine.

Any help is highly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Eagi is internal interface.

Just run it on asterisk and send out #2 via netcat or other command line tool.

```
0<&# close stdin
netcat -u host port <2 # get input from file handle number 2
```